# What was the original colour of the Colosseum (Flavian Amphitheatre)?

Tags: ancient-rome, architecture

Most of the remains of Roman buildings that we see today are white, merely because paint decays much faster than the structure of the building which is naturally whitish. Looking at many of the statues, it is well known that they were painted. We're basically looking at history through a black and white camera.

I've tried to find out what were the original colours of the Colosseum but Google search didn't turn up anything.

What were the original colours of the Colosseum? A reasonable guess based on what other similar buildings looked like will also be accepted if no better information is available.

Comment: Pompeii might offer hints on the colors that were used to decorate buildings at the time. And back in Greece, the [Parthenon](https://www.livescience.com/649-parthenon-riot-color.html) is thought to have been "brilliant shades of red, blue and green."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Rosella Rea, director of the Colosseum, in the restoration from 2013 they found traces of it being brightly painted in red, ochre, blue and green.

[image: https://latunicadeneso.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/colores-coliseo.jpg]

[Dr. Rossella Rea, the Colosseum’s Archaeological Director: “We need to imagine a building with extreme contrasts of color,”](https://rometheimperialfora19952010.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/rome-archaeology-dr-rossella-rea-the-colosseums-archaeological-director-we-need-to-imagine-a-building-with-extreme-contrasts-of-color-rome-january-10-2013-ap-news-usa-18-jan-2013/)

[Restoration Work on Colosseum to Reveal its True Colors](http://www.italymagazine.com/news/restoration-work-colosseum-reveal-its-true-colors)

Comment: Damn. No computer reconstruction with those colours?

Comment: Do note however that the restoration work (which is pretty much complete) was to make the Colosseum *amber* again. ([this link](http://www.rainews.it/dl/rainews/articoli/Il-restauro-del-Colosseo-visto-da-molto-vicino-riemerge-il-colore-originale-grazie-acqua-d0566cb8-75a9-452b-add7-c44967cf240a.html) explains it, but it is in Italian). Though it is true that it had plenty of colourful frescos all over the place.

Comment: @Marakai http://www.thecultureconcept.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Prima-Porta-Full-Statue-in-Colour.jpg  something in this line.

Comment: @CptEric yes along those lines. I've seen a fair number done for statues. Not for buildings

Comment: @Marakai partial color reconstruction of the pantheon, greece: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/74/9a/6a/749a6a61604ec46f4e3968bc008cdcbe.jpg   detail of section of another temple: http://factsanddetails.com/media/2/20120222-Athena_Aphaia-W_Pediment_colored.JPG